# How can I update Table A columns (Price & Limit) from table B & C

Tags: sql

[image: Table to update]

How can I update data into Table A with Single Update query?

Comment: Don't copy data between tables. Create a view instead - it will always have up-to-date data.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like : (I haven't tested it)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE tableA 
SET tableA.Price = tableB.Price
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.Item = tableB.Item

UPDATE tableA 
SET tableA.Limit = tableC.Limit
FROM tableA, tableC
WHERE tableA.CName = tableC.CName

COMMIT
```

Comment: tried but no rows updated

Comment: At first, try only with `tableA` and `tableB`, like : `UPDATE tableA SET tableA.Price = tableB.Price FROM tableA, tableB WHERE tableA.Item = tableB.Item`

Comment: Yes single condition is working but not both, how can i get both columns filled in a single query?

Comment: i believe you should use **transaction**, i edited my post

Answer (score 0):

try this request

```
UPDATE A a
SET a.price = b.price, a.limit = c.limit 
FROM B b, C c
WHERE a.item = b.item and a.cname = c.cname;
```

Comment: giving error Incorrect syntax near 'a' , and removing alias giving 0 rows updated

Comment: `UPDATE A
SET 
    A.price = B.price, 
    A.limit = C.limit
FROM A
INNER JOIN
B
ON A.item = B.item
INNER JOIN 
C
ON  A.cname = C.cname;`